# Update-SPProfilePhotoStore on New MySiteLocation throws exception on Deleted MySiteLocation

Tags: 2013, user-profile, picture, spprofilephotostore, mysite

I had a malfunctioning MySite located at `http://mysite:8080`, which I deleted. I created a new web app at `http://portal:8080` successfully, the MySiteHost Site Collection successfully, set up mysite in User Profile Service Application successfully, ran the three MySite timer jobs, and the Incremental Sync timer job as well.

With my admin account I managed to create a mysite and look at my properties. Updating properties in AD, running the increental sync timer job and see the change at my mysite.

I've set the SharePoint User property "Picture" to AD property "thumbnailPhoto" (import only) and uploaded an image to AD (using AD Photo Edit). Running the incremental timer job (again) gives no result in UPSA nor on the mysite. I try to run the following powershell command with user SP_Farm:

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation http://portal:8080/
```

which gives the following (odd) exception pointing to the old mysitehost:

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore : The Web application at http://mysite:8080/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed
the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new reques
t URL mapping to the intended application.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation http://portal:8080/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...ofilePhotoStore:SPCmdletUserProfilePhotoStore) [Update-S
   PProfilePhotoStore], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PowerShell.SPCmdletUserProfilePhotoStore
```

[image]

Why does that happen, and how can I reslove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try Updating the User Profile via Powershell.

```
$ap = Get-SPServiceApplication –Name "User Profile Service Application"
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication –Identity $ap –MySiteHostLocation "http://portal:8080"
```

Also, have you tried restarting IIS/UPS?

Comment: Nice tip! I've reset the IIS and MySite Settings via GUI in Central Admin. But I'll try PowerShell later. I'll keep you posted on the outcome.

Comment: I'd also look into if any remnants of the old mysite webapp. Did you have any errors when deleting it? I'd take a look though the ULS logs and search for http://mysite:8080. I'd try to find the webapplication/sitecollection etc through powershell. You may have to do a stsadm -o deleteconfigurationobject as a last resort.

Comment: so what happened Benny?

Comment: :) good deal Benny. Glad to have helped!